# Java JSON parsing with the Nashorn API

Tags: java, javascript, json

Some time ago I found a [website](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/) about the Java Nashorn API which allows you to run JavaScript from Java code. I thought about creating a [JSON](http://json.org/) parser in pure Java (without external libraries) which makes use of this API and the JavaScript function `JSON.parse()`
My goal is to make this parser as fast, resource efficient and easy as possible.
So I would like to know if the following code is efficient compared to JSON libraries and how I could improve it in terms of performance and accuracy.

## Code

**JSONFile.java**

```
package com.example.json;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JSONFile {

    public static final JSONObject parseFromPath(String path) {
        return parseFromString(TextFile.readFromPath(path));
    }

    public static final JSONObject parseFromResource(String resource) {
        return parseFromString(TextFile.readFromResource(resource));
    }

    public static final JSONObject parseFromURL(String url) {
        return parseFromString(TextFile.readFromURL(url));
    }

    public static final JSONObject parseFromString(String json) {
        try {
            ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
            engine.eval(TextFile.readFromResource("/js/jsonparser.js"));
            return new JSONObject(((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("parseJSON", json));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**JSONObject.java**

```
package com.example.json;

import java.util.Map;

public class JSONObject {

    private Map<String, Object> map;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONObject(Object object) {
        map = (Map<String, Object>) object;
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return (String) map.get(key);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
        return (boolean) map.get(key);
    }

    public int getInteger(String key) {
        return (int) map.get(key);
    }

    public float getFloat(String key) {
        return (float) map.get(key);
    }

    public JSONObject getObject(String key) {
        return new JSONObject(map.get(key));
    }

    public JSONArray getArray(String key) {
        return new JSONArray((Object[]) map.get(key));
    }

}
```

**JSONArray.java**

```
package com.example.json;

public class JSONArray {

    private Object[] array;

    public JSONArray(Object[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    public String getString(int index) {
        return (String) array[index];
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(int index) {
        return (boolean) array[index];
    }

    public int getInteger(int index) {
        return (int) array[index];
    }

    public float getFloat(int index) {
        return (float) array[index];
    }

    public JSONObject getObject(int index) {
        return new JSONObject(array[index]);
    }

    public JSONArray getArray(int index) {
        return new JSONArray((Object[]) array[index]);
    }

}
```

**TextFile.java**

```
package com.example.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class TextFile {

    public static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static final String readFromPath(String path) {
        try {
            return read(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(path), StandardOpenOption.READ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static final String readFromResource(String resource) {
        return read(TextFile.class.getResourceAsStream(resource));
    }

    public static final String readFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            return read(new URL(url).openStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final String read(InputStream is) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) builder.append(line + LINE_SEPARATOR);
            reader.close();
            System.gc();
            return builder.toString().trim();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**/js/sonparser.js**

```
function parseJSON(json) { return convert(JSON.parse(json)); }

function convert(object) {
    if (isObject(object)) return toHashMap(object);
    if (isArray(object)) return toArray(object);
    return object;
}

function toHashMap(object) {
    var map = new java.util.HashMap();
    for (key in object) map.put(key, convert(object[key]));
    return map;
}

function toArray(object) {
    var array = Java.to(object, "java.lang.Object[]");
    for (var index = 0, len = array.length; index < len; index++) array[index] = convert(array[index]);
    return array;
}

function isObject(object) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === "[object Object]"; }
function isArray(object) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === "[object Array]"; }
```

## Example

**example.json** (Source: http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

**JSONTest.java**

```
public class JSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray employees = JSONFile.parseFromResource("/json/example.json").getArray("employees");
        for (int index = 0, len = employees.length(); index < len; index++) {
            JSONObject employee = employees.getObject(index);
            System.out.println(employee.getString("lastName") + ", " + employee.getString("firstName"));
        }
    }

}
```

**Result**

```
Doe, John
Smith, Anna
Jones, Peter
```

I made some heavy changes to the code since the last edit. (Added JSONObject.java & JSONArray.java & TextFile.java and small improvements to JSONFile.java) So now it is much easier to use the code, as seen in the example.

Comment: This can be done more easily using a `ScriptObjectMirror`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method names and argument types

```
public static final JSONObject parseFromPath(String path) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parseFromResource(String resource) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parseFromURL(String url) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parseFromString(String json) { .. }
```

A school of thought is that one can also use the argument type(s) to simplify the method names. In other words, if the method name says it is parsing from `Path`, why not accept a `Path` object then?

```
public static final JSONObject parse(Path path) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parse(InputStream resource) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parse(URL url) { ... }

public static final JSONObject parse(String json) { .. }
```

An additional benefit of this is that you eliminate to risk of calling `parseFromString()` accidentally, when the argument is really a URL.

## Auto-boxing

You rely on auto-boxing for your `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes. The problem with this is that you get a nasty `NullPointerException` if there is no mapped/array value, and the JVM is trying to unbox the `null` to one of the primitive types. Also, if the value is not the desired primitive type wrapper object, you will get a `ClassCastException` too. You should consider checking for that, for example:

```
public class JSONArray {

    // ...

    public int getInteger(int index) {
        Object value = array[index];
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer) value;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-integer value at array index: " + index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Positive points:**

1. It might seem obvious, but adding the `length` method was a good choice.
2. I agree with [h.j.k](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/107856/120967) in general. I just want to emphasize that your choice might make your API more user-friendly, so they can simply pass the String. But again, I understand that in general, separation of concerns and abstraction are good practices and I would make the same comment.
3. Most importantly, the fact that you created something that the world needed and didn't exist (please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Other potential option:**

I emphasize it's a grey area and depends on the user:

1. Adding `toString` method.